# Snowflake query using binds

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a query which we want to run using bind values by declaring it something as below. But its giving syntax error. My questions are as below

1)If there exists any possible way to manually run queries on the worksheet using bind values in snowflake, something like below? Its giving error when tried to run the query by declaring the binds in below fashion.

2)If we set the "USE_CACHED_RESULTS" to TRUE(which is default ) , and if the actual value for these binds varies for each execution execution of the query, will the query still be able to use the result cache?

3)And considering the filter on date column TDT in below query is having a bigger range i.e. covering all the table data so it wont be pruning any partition. Is there any other optimization technique exists which could be utilized to prune partition on other possible predicates with function on them like upper(CH), trim(ILVL) etc in below query?

```
`
SET b1='24-mar-2022';
SET b2='27-mar-2022';
SET b3='ABC';
SET b4='DEF';

SELECT
    ...
    ROUND(COALESCE(AAG, 0)) ,  ROUND(COALESCE(AIN, 0), 2), TTX,  ROUND(T_CN * 100.0 / NULLIF(TTX, 0)) AS TPCT,
    ROUND(TAMT * 100.0 / NULLIF(TAMT, 0)) 
FROM
    (  SELECT      ILVL,  AVG(AT / TCNT) OVER () AS AAG,   AVG(IT / TCNT) OVER () AS AIN, SUM(TCNT) OVER () AS TTX, SUM(TAMT) OVER () AS TAMT,
            SUM(TCNT) OVER (PARTITION BY ILVL) AS T_CN,  SUM(TAMT) OVER (PARTITION BY ILVL) AS TAMT
        FROM    TAB1
        WHERE
            ILVL is not null and trim(ILVL) != 'N/A'     and trim(ILVL) != ''    and trim(ILVL) != 'XXXX'   and TDT between :b1   and :b2
            and (contains(:b3, upper(CH)))       and (contains(:b4, upper(ST)))
    ) AS SUB1
GROUP BY    SOURCE,ILVL, AAG,AIN, TTX,TPCT,AMT_PCT
ORDER BY    1,2,3...;`
```

Tried running the query with bind values but getting syntax error.

Comment: It might help to see the error you are getting.  Also, if this is being executed as just straight SQL, then referencing your variables should be done using a $, rather than a :.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables#using-variables-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MikeWalton the "$" sign worked for the binds and made the query run without any error.

Again as per my second question the the main post, Is snowflake is trying to scan the underlying literal values of each bind value for every execution of the query and that is how its able to utilize the result cache or some other technique it uses? As because scanning underlying literal for every execution will have CPU overhead and then there will be no benefit of bind variable usage. Correct me if wrong?

The query gives below profile and as mentioned in my 3rd point, its going for table full scan where it spent 95% of the time and scans all the partition. So is there any pruning method possible on the function/expression on columns(say for e.g. upper(CH) in our query) which will reduce the partition scan? AS because requirement is to scan all the data for input date range of TDT. So wanted to see if any other filter in the query can be utilized to prune the partitions while full scan.

```
Profile Overview (Finished)
Total Execution Time
(2.2s) 100.0%
Processing
19.6%
Remote Disk I/O
77.0%
Initialization
3.3%

Statistics
Scan progress
100.00%
Bytes scanned
216.69MB
Percentage scanned from cache
0.00%
Partitions scanned
35
Partitions total
35
```